# VB Syntax and Expression errors

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

Hey I have done this code for a Multiple choice quiz,but keep getting **two syntax errors** and a **Expression expected** but have no clue how to solve it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim questions(2, 4) As String    
    Dim answers(2) As String    
    Dim quesNum As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Text = "Operational Strategies Test"
        GetQuestions()
        quesNum = 1    
        Label1.Text = "Question " & quesNum & " of " & answers.Length    
        Label2.Text = questions(0, 0)

        RadioButton1.Text = questions(0, 1)    
        RadioButton2.Text = questions(0, 2)    
        RadioButton3.Text = questions(0, 3)    
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
        If quesNum > 1 Then    
            quesNum -= 1    
            Label1.Text = "Question " & quesNum & " of 3"    
            Label2.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 0)    
            RadioButton1.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 1)    
            RadioButton2.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 2)    
            RadioButton3.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 3)   

            If btnNext.Text = "Submit" Then    
                btnNext.Text = "Next"    
            End If    
        End If   
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then    
            answers(quesNum - 1) = RadioButton1.Text    
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then    
            answers(quesNum - 1) = RadioButton2.Text    
        ElseIf RadioButton3.Checked = True Then    
            answers(quesNum - 1) = RadioButton3.Text    
        End If

        RadioButton1.Focus()

        If quesNum < 3 Then    
            quesNum += 1    
            Label1.Text = "Question " & quesNum & " of " & answers.Length    
            Label2.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 0)    
            RadioButton1.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 1)    
            RadioButton2.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 2)    
            RadioButton3.Text = questions(quesNum - 1, 3)

            If quesNum = 3 Then    
                btnNext.Text = "Submit"    
            End If    
        Else    
            MarkTest()    
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetQuestions()    
        questions = New String(,) {{"How many colors are in a rainbow?", "5", "6", "7", "7"}, _    
        {"Who starred in Pirates of the Caribbean?", "Johnny Depp", "John Malkovich", "John Cusack", "Johnny Depp"}, _    
        {"What is the capital of Florida?", "Miami", "Tallahassee", "Jacksonville", "Tallahassee"}}    
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You mean [these](http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/755/xxd7.png) errors?

On VS 2010+ you don't need to do that... [here](http://i.imgur.com/POvBtRd.png)

Comment: You're missing a "Dim" before "questions", please [check.](http://i.imgur.com/POvBtRd.png)

Comment: Hey,thanks for the help.I am still getting these errors after the changes ? [link](http://i.imgur.com/TBneykk.jpg?1)

Comment: @SomeNickName no, he declared his `questions` array so he doesn't need any `Dim`.

Comment: @Vland, sorry, i didn't see the first declaration which wasn't on code before the edit, that's why i typed "Dim" myself on the example i provided, but he just has to delete it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
questions = {{"How many colors are in a rainbow?", "5", "6", "7", "7"}, _
{"Who starred in Pirates of the Caribbean?", "Johnny Depp", "John Malkovich", "John Cusack", "Johnny Depp"},
{"What is the capital of Florida?", "Miami", "Tallahassee", "Jacksonville", "Tallahassee"}}
```

and read here

[How to: Initialize a Multidimensional Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sxy840k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx#fbid=NWQbYOPac76)

Comment: And mine was exactly like this except i didn't see you've already declarated the "questions"... nvm.